# Symfony Form: translation of attr

Tags: symfony, translation

I'm trying to translate help messages that I created on my form using attr array but I can't translate it. Does anybody know how to do it?

This is an example:

```
->add('facebook_sharing_title', null, 
    array(
    'label' => "establishment.edit.facebooksharingtitle",
    'required' => false,
    'attr' => array('help' => '70 caractères max. conseillé')
    )
)
```

As you can see, the translation o the label is ok. However, if I do the same for help it doesn't work. I can't find anything about it in the symfony site. I know how to do it on twig but I would like to do it on the form type.

Comment: Ask for the translator in the constructor. Then `array('help' => $this->translator->trans('establishement.edit.facebooksharing.attr_help'))` or something similar

Comment: Thanks Touki. I'm gonna try it. ;)

Comment: It worked well but I finally decided to add a trans in my form template and it detected the translation automatically. ;)